# What is the weapon Teal'c is using at the beginning of "Off the Grid"?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

At 1:12 into *Stargate SG1* S9E16, Teal'c is seen firing a weapon more like a weapon of the Tau'ri.  But I don't recognize it from earlier missions...He usually uses the Staff Weapon.

What is this weapon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Internet Movie Firearms Database](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Stargate_SG-1_-_Season_9), it's a Heckler & Koch MP7 (with added sights).

I've seen him use the same P90s the rest of the team uses, but this time they had different gear.

[image]